# How to batch array_map?

Tags: php

I have this code that combines 3 arrays using array_map() to store them to a csv file to the format I like:

```
$list = array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3);
$filename = ‘file.csv’;
$fp = fopen($filename, ‘w’);
foreach ($list as $fields){
 fputcsv($fp,$fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

The problem is the array contains millions of rows so whenever I run my script, It always throws a Fatal Error: Allowed memory exhausted.

Is there a way to batch the storing of array_map() to the variable $list?

I tried finding a solution for this online for a few days now and all the solutions I found is not compatible with my code. I’m basically on my last straw here and I’m open on trying any idea you guys could come up with!

Comment: Why not separately save the data of each array? why combine them? any specific reason?

Comment: So that its on a single csv file. I need them to be on a separate column on the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they all have the same number of elements, loop over the first and add the rest into the write without having to build a new array with all of the values...

```
$filename = ‘file.csv’;
$fp = fopen($filename, ‘w’);
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value1){
    fputcsv($fp, [$value1, $array2[$key], $array3[$key]]);
}
fclose($fp);
```

If your arrays have different keys, you can use [`next`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) and [`current`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) to iterate over the second and third arrays irrespective of the keys themselves...

```
reset($array2);
reset($array3);

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value1) {
    print_r([$value1, current($array2), current($array3)]);
    next($array2);
    next($array3);
}
```

Comment: This wont work since the array is not of the same value. Is there a way to make them work when they’re not the same value? Not creating s new array sounds great

Comment: as per my understanding, this will work if we do array_values of each array. @Nigel Ren please comment

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the same value, can you give a short example.

Comment: @NigelRen what is OP trying to say is that [$key] will not work as his keys for all three array is different. This is what I understood.

Comment: Yes, @Anant-Alivetodie is right

Comment: What do you mean with array_value? Could you give me an example on how that would work? Would love to try them

Comment: @rei https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php re-indexes an array with a numeric, zero-based index.

Comment: You can also use `current` & `next` to grab the corresponding entry from the second (and same with the third) array, https://3v4l.org/oEDkt

Comment: `$array1 = array_filter(array_values($array1));
$array2 = array_filter(array_values($array2)); 
$array3 = array_filter(array_values($array3));

$filename = ‘file.csv’;
$fp = fopen($filename, ‘w’);
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value1){
    fputcsv($fp, [$value1, $array2[$key], $array3[$key]]);
}
fclose($fp);`

Comment: Is this solution specific to php version? I’m getting syntax error from your code.

Comment: Not easy for me to update this as I am on my phone.

Comment: @Rei code is not giving any error with sample data  : https://3v4l.org/puLj5

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie using `array_values` will copy the array!

Comment: @NigelRen it will re-index array keys to 01,2,3............ then your code will work

Comment: @Rei, I've added a new option which doesn't need the same keys to work.

Comment: @NigelRen, I just tested your code in higher version of php and it works. But I’m using php version 5.2 and I cant upgrade it. I’m getting a syntax error unexpected ‘[‘ on the fputcsv($fp, [ ]); line. Can I get some assistance on what to search for here? What is that bracket called in php when used like that?

Comment: Sorry if this is a really dumb question

Comment: @Rei - you can replace the `[]` and use `array($value1, $array2[$key], $array3[$key])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a more memory for PHP process.
2. It's possible to process the arrays in chunks to reduce the amount of memory used at any given time. Here is one way you could do this:

Create a function that will process a chunk of the arrays and write the resulting rows to the CSV file. The function should take three arguments: the arrays to process, the start index, and the number of items to process.

```php
    function processChunk($array1, $array2, $array3, $start, $numItems) {
      $filename = ‘file.csv’;
      $fp = fopen($filename, ‘w’);
    
      // Process the chunk of arrays, starting at the specified index
      // and processing up to $numItems items.
      for ($i = $start; $i < $start + $numItems && $i < count($array1); $i++) {
        $fields = array_map(null, $array1[$i], $array2[$i], $array3[$i]);
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
      }
    
      fclose($fp);
    }
```

Use a loop to process the arrays in chunks. For example, you could process 1000 items at a time. Inside the loop, call the processChunk() function to process each chunk of the arrays.

```php
    $chunkSize = 1000;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i += $chunkSize) {
      processChunk($array1, $array2, $array3, $i, $chunkSize);
    }
```

This should allow you to process the arrays in smaller chunks, which should reduce the amount of memory used. You can use for this cron.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, would try this

Comment: this will not work : `$fields = array_map(null, $array1[$i], $array2[$i], $array3[$i]);`

Comment: Yup did not work, nice idea though! Gave me something to learn